# What's the benefit of cap “and” cork?

Tags: bottling

Some beers, like Lindemann's lambics, come in a bottle that resembles a champaigne bottle (but smaller), with a cork -- *and* a bottlecap.  What does the cap add to this?  Why is it there?

(By "resembles a champaigne bottle" I mean the glass is thicker and the bottom has that "indent" characteristic of bottles whose contents are under higher-than-normal pressure.)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The bottle cap has the same purpose as a wire cage-- to ensure that the cork doesn't pop itself under the bottle's interior pressure.

Comment: I hadn't realized that the pressure could do that.  (I guess, now that you mention it, champaigne does tend to have wire cages, though most wines don't.)  But is a cap really strong enough to prevent that?

Comment: I don't have direct experience in bottling that beer, or beers of that nature, but apparently so.  I think it's mostly precautionary, and probably a small cost to prevent accidents (and a poor reputation).

Comment: Prevent entirely? Probably not - but you wouldn't *want* that either, @Monica. In a "catastrophic failure" scenario, popping a cap is preferable to breaking the bottle itself. Under normal conditions, the fermentation produces *juust* enough pressure to give the wine/beer a nice sparkling carbonation and the cap a satisfying "pop" - the over-cap would need only to keep it in place long enough for you to enjoy it.